# How do I configure Composer to use a different path on Windows when my Application Data folder is remote?

Tags: windows, active-directory, composer-php

When I install composer on Windows 10, with active directory (meaning some of my user files live off on a server elsewhere), I get the following error when attempting to install:

> Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
>     [InvalidArgumentException]
>     $from (\AD.LOCAL\SYSTEM\Users[path]\Application Data\Composer\ad.local\system\Users[path]\Applicat
>     ion Data\Composer\vendor\bin/boris) and $to (\AD.LOCAL\SYSTEM\Users[path]\Application Data\Composer\vendor
>     [path]\boris\bin\boris) must be absolute paths.

...very likely because my "Application Data" folder is not on my local machine.

How can I get around this. Windows composer install doesn't give me much in the way of options.

(Or, alternately, if I'm misinterpreting the cause of the problem, what is actually going on and how do I fix it?)

Comment: How is cygwin involved ? I see no reference on `https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md`

Comment: Good point.  Originally I was working entirely in Cygwin, but I have identical problems at the dos prompt.

Comment: Seems to be triggered by this check in Composer `return substr($path, 0, 1) === '/' || substr($path, 1, 1) === ':';` All your paths are with backslashes and no drive reference. Is that above error from when you run it using the normal command prompt? Did you install composer with [the installer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)?

Comment: Yes, the error is identical regardless of the shell.
Also yes, it was installed with the installer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue was during the installation there is a flag that allows you to set the installation directory.

The bin file from the path in the error message `vendor/bin/boris` doesn't look familiar to me and I am going to assume you completed an installation and a command had failed. There is a `COMPOSER_HOME` environment variable that impacts where a number of items are stored. This defaults to `${APPDATA}/Composer`, if there are issues writing under that path for any reason, you can change the path by setting the `COMPOSER_HOME` variable for your user.

Comment: The env variable didn't already exist, but I added it and it worked brilliantly. Much cleaner than my own solution. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, it will not be defined unless you define it. The default value of it when undefined is equivalent to setting it to `${APPDATA}/Composer`

Answer (score 0):

Created a local windows admin account, installed the functions from that account, and then put the local admins roaming folder in my PATH.  Ugly, but effective.